# CMake build with gcc/g++ fails on Windows

Tags: windows, gcc, cmake

I've installed CMake 3.14.4 (from cmake-3.14.4-win64-x64.msi) and GCC 5.1.0 (from tdm64-gcc-5.1.0-2.exe) on Windows 7 Enterprise and 10 Home (64-bit).

I'm trying to build a `.LIL` from cpp/hpp source files [github sources.](https://github.com/ot4i/iib-stats-writer-statsd) The CMakeLists.txt refers to includes directory from the COTS install. A header file in the includes directory has this if-else and the CMake build always errors out by falling in the last else block below:

```
# if defined(_M_AMD64)
#  include <wchar.h>
#  if BIP_CXX11_SUPPORT
typedef char16_t CciChar;
#  else
typedef wchar_t CciChar;
#  endif
typedef __int64 CciInt;
typedef unsigned __int64 CciCount;
#  define __CCI_WINDOWS__
# else
#  error The C plugin interface for IBM Integration Bus is only available 
for 64-bit Windows x86-64 systems
#endif
```

Steps:

```
1. c:\iib-swm\build>cmake -DIIB_INSTALL_DIR=C:\Progra~1\IBM\IIB\10.0.0.12 
-G "MinGW Makefiles" ../source
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.1.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/software/C++Tools/tdm- 
gcc/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/software/C++Tools/tdm- 
gcc/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/iib-swm/build
```

This is the content of CMakeSystem.cmake after this step:

```
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM "Windows-6.1.7601")
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME "Windows")
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION "6.1.7601")
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "AMD64")



set(CMAKE_SYSTEM "Windows-6.1.7601")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "Windows")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION "6.1.7601")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "AMD64")

set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING "FALSE")

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_LOADED 1)

2. c:\iib-swm\build>cmake --build .

   -- Configuring done
   -- Generating done
   -- Build files have been written to: C:/iib-swm/build
   [ 33%] Building CXX object 
   CMakeFiles/statsdsw.dir/StatsdStatsWriter.cpp.obj
   In file included from 
   C:/Progra~1/IBM/IIB/10.0.0.12/server/include/plugin/BipCci.h:14:0,
             from 
   C:/Progra~1/IBM/IIB/10.0.0.12/server/include/plugin/BipCsi.h:14,
             from C:\iib-swm\source\StatsdStatsWriter.hpp:13,
             from C:\iib-swm\source\StatsdStatsWriter.cpp:10:
   C:/Progra~1/IBM/IIB/10.0.0.12/server/include/plugin/BipCos.h:170:4: 
   error: #error The C plugin inter
   face for IBM Integration Bus is only available for 64-bit Windows x86- 
   64 systems
   #  error The C plugin interface for IBM Integration Bus is only 
   available for 64-bit Windows x86-64
   systems
      ^
   CMakeFiles\statsdsw.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 
   'CMakeFiles/statsdsw.dir/StatsdStatsWriter.
   cpp.obj' failed
   mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** 
   [CMakeFiles/statsdsw.dir/StatsdStatsWriter.cpp.obj] Error 3
   CMakeFiles\Makefile2:71: recipe for target 
   'CMakeFiles/statsdsw.dir/all' failed
   mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/statsdsw.dir/all] Error 130
   Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
   mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 130
```

I just can't understand that even when CMake recognizes the system processor as AMD64, it doesn't translate to `_M_AMD64` in the includes .h file? I've trawled CMake and related resources on the net. Tried running CMake as admin, shortened the path in which git project was cloned to without luck.

PS: My only brush with cpp was at Uni 15 years ago, so please have mercy my lords (and ladies) if I've missed to C the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`_M_AMD64` appears to be specific to Visual Studio compilers.  The question is confusing because it suggests that CMake is doing the pre-processing.  It doesn't.  You are using `gcc`. `gcc` doesn't appear to implement the Visual Studio specific pre-processor macros.

You'll either have to alter the code to work with `gcc` or define the missing macros yourself using a CMake command like `target_compile_definitions`.

Be aware that the [README](https://github.com/ot4i/iib-stats-writer-statsd/blob/master/README.md) file says to use Visual Studio 2015 for building on Windows.

Comment: All good suggestions Fred. Re your first para, i understood that CMake would set the processor/bitness info for the build stage otherwise, with the steps i have got, how would the compiler know these attributes of the target system?

Comment: @PKay You can see the command line options that CMake has chosen by using `make VERBOSE=1`.  For me CMake doesn't set processor at all.  CMake just uses the compilers defaults for the target it was created for.  The version of `gcc` I'm using is built to generate code for `'-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'`.  Of course you can override these if you want something specific like `-march=native` which will compile something for the local target but may not run on other targets.

Comment: i built the dll on Win10 (my laptop) using Cmake and VS 2015 specifying CMake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64". This is recognised (registered) on Win10 by COTS product after restart. However, the dll fails to register on Win 7 Enterprise SP1 (My Dev WS). Windows states that  VS2015 creates a dependency on Universal CRT when built using Win 10 SDK (as in my case). UCRT is not available on Win 7 SP1. Moreover, our environments have Win 2008 Server R2 SP1. So, even with the build performed with correct processor & bitness, i have to factor in different flavors of Win OS.